# Can we write logics in Terraform Code (IaC) anything like using count.index[ ]?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, instance, terraform-provider-aws

While, I was working with Terraform I had a question;  I will be able to destroy some specific resources using terraform destroy --target [] --target [] or terraform state -rm ; this is okay if we have 50 servers but what if I have 1000 servers and would like to terminate such as odd number instances or even number instances using the array numbers in the list or could we write a script to gather all the corrupted instances and execute that script to terminate all those instances and make that script reusable!!

Is there any way for this, I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find any solution; may be this question is dumb but I was just curious!!!!

Is there any documentation that explains this is would not be possible through terraform!!!!

Comment: Have you looked at `index` function here https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the count as an output:

```
output "server_count" {
  value = var.server_count
}
```

and write a script (shell/Python/etc) that takes that count as an argument and uses it to taint every odd resource:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: taint_odd_servers.sh <num servers>

SERVER_COUNT=$1

i=0
while [ $i -lt $SERVER_COUNT ]
do
  REMAINDER=$(( $i % 2 ))
  if [ $REMAINDER -ne 0 ]
  then
    terraform taint "your_server_resource[${i}]"
  fi
  i=$(($i+1))
done
```

You could then call that script like:

```
taint_odd_servers.sh $(terraform output server_count)
```